# Is it possible to change the clickable area of links using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a code block looking something like this:

```
<p class="cont">
 <a href="otherpage.php" class="link"><img src="test.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100"/></a>
</p>
```

and I've got some CSS like this:

```
.cont {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.cont:hover {
  background-color:#CCC;
}
```

My question is, if it's possible to change the size of the link area, so that it takes up the whole

area thus making it clickable - not only the image. I've tried giving width and height to the .link class and use display:block but it doesn't do the trick. Is it even possible?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227618/big-clickable-areas-on-a-web-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/sSGJV/
Or with `200px` dimensions: http://jsfiddle.net/sSGJV/1/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" />
    <br />
    Click to go to the Googles.
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    display: block;
    border: 3px dashed #000;
    text-align: center
}
```

As you can see, you can click anywhere inside the `<a>` tag.

Comment: +1, the only non-Javascript way I know; there might be problems in IE6 IIRC

Answer (score 2):

In short yes, there is a great blog post about just this subject that can be found here: http://csswizardry.com/2011/01/maximising-hit-area-for-usability/

Comment: That works fine if it's just text. The problem is when there's an image inside.

Comment: <style>
.cont a{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:block;
}
.cont a:hover {
  background-color:#CCC;
  
}
.cont a img {
  display:block;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

I had what seemed like a similar issue and resolved it by adding style z-index:3 to the wrapping div.